# Same sku in different row in cart | Grouped product | Magento

Tags: magento

If we have same sku present in different grouped product, i would need to display that sku in different rows in cart.
For example,
I have a grouped product sku GP001 which has the child skus (SKU0001,SKU0002 and SKU0003).
I have another grouped product sku GP002 which has the child skus (SKU0001,SKU0004 and SKU0005).

Scenarios:
1) Add GP001 to cart
2) Add GP002 to cart

Expected :
SKU0001 shoule be present in cart as two separate rows.

1) Add GP001 to cart
2) Add SKU0001 to cart

Expected :
SKU0001 shoule be present in cart as single row with increased qty.

Comment: you need this only on cart or entire order flow?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I would need this for entire order flow.